# Water Heater in crawl space

Tags: water-heater

I am concerned that the hot water heater and furnace in the duplex I live in is not up to code. They are installed in a crawl space which is “maybe” 4 feet high. The space is dirt & the water heater is dug down about 12”. There appears to be no space above the water heater. The furnace is not dug down that deep.
Is this up to code in Wisconsin, Marathon County? I don’t know who to call.

Comment: Sounds pretty bad. Can you upload a picture?

Comment: Gas or electric?

Comment: A general note about code: what matters is not the current code, but what the code was at the time of construction. There's a great many things that were acceptable a few decades back that aren't now, and there's usually no requirement to actually fix those issues.

Comment: Unless you change something in that system that requires an inspection, in which case they can refuse to allow it to continue to be "grandfathered" (the colloquial term for accepting something from a previous code).

Comment: It might not be too bad for a electric heater but not acceptable for gas.

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation? And yes, are these electric or gas appliances we are talking about here?